# WinForms RichTextBox saves image as pngblip which cannot be displayed

Tags: .net, image, richtextbox

I am using winforms with .net 4.7.2.

I have a problem when pasting an image form the clipboard into a RichTextBox.
On some platforms (Win2012 and Win2016) it stores the image in the RTF as a \pngblip. When I load this again in a RichTextBox, the image is not displayed.

On Windows 7, it stores the image as \wmetafile8 which displays fine.

I have uploaded a [very simple sample project](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1B5B1S0WsF6PQdkZUMggcO3v3oh6Uy3Pl) to google drive. Press the top button to put an image on the clipboard and paste it in to the source rich text box. Then see how it is rendered in another richtextbox and what the rtf looks like.

This works differently on Windows 7 and windows 2012.
On windows 7, the target rtf starts with

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1030{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}}
{\*\generator Msftedit 5.41.21.2510;}\viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs17{\pict\wmetafile8\picw423\pich423\picwgoal240\pichgoal240 
0100090000...
```

Note the "generator Msftedit" part.
On windows 2012, I get

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\nouicompat\deflang1030{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}}
{\*\generator Riched20 6.3.9600}\viewkind4\uc1 
\pard\f0\fs17{\pict{\*\picprop{\sp{\sn wzDescription}{\sv Image}}{\sp{\sn posv}{\sv 1}}
}\pngblip\picw423\pich423\picwgoal240\pichgoal240 
895...
```

Here the "generator Riched20" is different? I think this is key?

The rtf with the \pngblip cannot be rendered by a RichTextBox - neither on Windows 7 nor on Windows 2012. The \wmetafile renders fine.

This is of course just a sample app - in the real program, the user will paste an image which was put on the clipboard by another application, the rtf will be saved to a database, and it will later be displayed by a different form.

And converting everything to use HTML instead is not an option, since we have an existing database with tens of thousands of RTF entries.

Comment: Yes, that is the key.  Different richtextbox versions, 2.0 vs 5.0.  Later versions use different flavors of RTF.  You can repro this on your own machine by using Wordpad.exe to create the RTF file.  Using version 5 in your own program is a simple workaround, available on XP and later: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34358642/17034

Comment: Thanks Hans! It turned out that I needed to do the opposite - set the ClassName to RichEdit20W to make it work. Apparently the pngblip support was added in a later version, but it's not really working.

Comment: Related issue on microsoft site: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/383903/richtextbox-fails-to-display-image.html