# RichTextBox Text alignment issue with .NET4.8

Tags: winforms, richtextbox, text-alignment, .net-4.6.1, .net-4.8

When compared the text alignment with RichTextBox, behavior has changed from .Net4.6.1 to .Net4.8.

Any help on how the earlier behavior of .Net 4.6.1 can be achieved in .Net4.8?

[image]

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        
        RichTextBox richTextBox1 = new RichTextBox()
        {
            Width = 300,
            Height = 20,
            Location = new Point(100, 100)
        };

        richTextBox1.Text = "中文_Dummy_Text";

        TextBox textBox = new TextBox()
        {
            Width = 300,
            Height = 20,
            Location = new Point(100, 200)
        };

        textBox.Text = "中文_Dummy_Text";

        this.Controls.Add(richTextBox1);
        this.Controls.Add(textBox);

    }
```

Comment: There was a big change in .NET 4.7, [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34358642/17034) was added to Winforms.  Yet another one without attribution :(  You can get the old one back with `cp.ClassName = "RichEdit20W";`  But realistically this is a simple mistake, just increase the Height a bit so the text can fit.

Comment: @HansPassant -  This issue occurs when text contains fonts like chinese/japanese. But when Text is only of english font then there is no issue.So adjusting height will have problem in current working scenarios.

Comment: @HansPassant tried code snippet you mentioned but with no success. however, I could see cp.className is already "RichEdit50W"

Answer (score 2):

Adding the runtime setting in App.Config (as below) reverted back to the older RTB in .NET 4.8.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
        <startup> 
            <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8"/>
        </startup>
      <runtime>
         <AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.System.Windows.Forms.DoNotLoadLatestRichEditControl=true"/>
      </runtime>
    
    </configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting multiline property to false also restores the earlier behavior of RTB

```
richTextBox1.Multiine = false
```